# How to write a for loop to generate a data point every time a process is executed

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array, graph

I'm trying to make a for loop in JavaScript which generates a point in a multi-dimensional array every time a certain process is executed.

I'm using a Google Charts graph and have more or less completely copied one of theirs into my own project, but the graph is using their points.

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTrendlines);

function drawTrendlines() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value y');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value Y');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, 0],    [1, 10, 5],   [2, 23, 15],  [3, 17, 9],   [4, 18, 10],  [5, 9, 5],
    [6, 11, 3],   [7, 27, 19],  [8, 33, 25],  [9, 40, 32],  [10, 32, 24], [11, 35, 27],
    [12, 30, 22], [13, 40, 32], [14, 42, 34], [15, 47, 39], [16, 44, 36], [17, 48, 40],
    [18, 52, 44], [19, 54, 46], [20, 42, 34], [21, 55, 47], [22, 56, 48], [23, 57, 49],
    [24, 60, 52], [25, 50, 42], [26, 52, 44], [27, 51, 43], [28, 49, 41], [29, 53, 45],
    [30, 55, 47], [31, 60, 52], [32, 61, 53], [33, 59, 51], [34, 62, 54], [35, 65, 57],
    [36, 62, 54], [37, 58, 50], [38, 55, 47], [39, 61, 53], [40, 64, 56], [41, 65, 57],
    [42, 63, 55], [43, 66, 58], [44, 67, 59], [45, 69, 61], [46, 69, 61], [47, 70, 62],
    [48, 72, 64], [49, 68, 60], [50, 66, 58], [51, 65, 57], [52, 67, 59], [53, 70, 62],
    [54, 71, 63], [55, 72, 64], [56, 73, 65], [57, 75, 67], [58, 70, 62], [59, 68, 60],
    [60, 64, 56], [61, 60, 52], [62, 65, 57], [63, 67, 59], [64, 68, 60], [65, 69, 61],
    [66, 70, 62], [67, 72, 64], [68, 75, 67], [69, 80, 72]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Analysis number'
    },
    colors: ['blue', 'darkgreen'],
    trendlines: {
      0: {type: 'linear', color: 'red', opacity: .5}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

How could I make a loop which would put the data in the form [x,y,Y] where x always increments by 1 (x++) whenever a process is executed (method `foo()` for example), and the y & Y values are recorded and graphed.

Values y and Y are two separate integer values which are obtained in a Ruby on Rails part of the project.

I'm not really sure where to even begin in terms of syntax, and have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990834/loop-in-order-to-generate-data-points-in-javascript), but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your data source for `y` and `Y`? Do you have arrays for those? You should learn [how to write a for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and make an attempt first.

Comment: They are from a ruby on rails part of the program, not arrays just normal integers.

Comment: So each `y` and `Y` for the chart has its own variable? Can you please edit the question to show what you mean?

Comment: Yes they are, and yeah no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array which you can insert into, loop over your data source, and then add it to the chart.

```
var rows = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 70; x++) {
    rows.push([x, y, Y]);
}
data.addRows(rows);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try

Comment: This will create 70 rows which all have the same value for `y` and `Y`. If you have an array of values to insert, you could do `rows.push([x, y[x], Y[x]])`